Exhaustive Troubleshooting Fails to Resolve Android Emulator (AVD) Issues with WHPX on Windows
I cannot make AVD work, and it's driving me nuts..
What i've tried:

Enabling/ disabling Hyper-V
Reinstall android studio twice (with deletes of the cached files)
Install latest C++ redistrbutes
Reinstall from SDK Tools: Android emulator, Android Emulator hypervisor driver, Android SDK Platform-tools
Uninstalled HAXM (since looks like it's deprecated), and I cannot install it from Android Studio (it wasnt working with it installed either)
Already up-to-update drivers (i'm using an intel i5-13400)
Created custom devices with >8 gbs of ram
Created custom devices with graphics software/ hardware/ auto.
I have over 300gbs free on ssd
Having the env set for sdk and tools
Tried different versions of android (35-28) with google play and without it if case, neither of them works.
Tried cold boot, didn't work.

The errors:

log file:
2024-11-18 12:49:56,179 [ 960809]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - C:\Users\Claudiu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_9_API_35
2024-11-18 12:49:56,255 [ 960885]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Android emulator version 35.2.10.0 (build_id 12414864) (CL:N/A)
2024-11-18 12:49:56,255 [ 960885]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Graphics backend: gfxstream
2024-11-18 12:49:56,255 [ 960885]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Found systemPath C:\Users\Claudiu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-35\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
2024-11-18 12:49:56,511 [ 961141]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
2024-11-18 12:49:56,511 [ 961141]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - IPv4 server found: 8.8.8.8
2024-11-18 12:49:56,511 [ 961141]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Ignore IPv6 address: 289b:3fd6:3801:0:6093:3fd6:3801:0
2024-11-18 12:49:56,511 [ 961141]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Ignore IPv6 address: 289b:3fd6:3801:0:6093:3fd6:3801:0
2024-11-18 12:49:56,511 [ 961141]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Ignore IPv6 address: 289b:3fd6:3801:0:6093:3fd6:3801:0
2024-11-18 12:49:56,511 [ 961141]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Ignore IPv6 address: 10a1:3fd6:3801:0:6093:3fd6:3801:0
2024-11-18 12:49:56,511 [ 961141]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Ignore IPv6 address: 10a1:3fd6:3801:0:6093:3fd6:3801:0
2024-11-18 12:49:56,511 [ 961141]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Ignore IPv6 address: 10a1:3fd6:3801:0:6093:3fd6:3801:0
2024-11-18 12:49:56,511 [ 961141]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\Claudiu\.android\avd\..\avd\Pixel_9_API_35.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2024-11-18 12:49:56,947 [ 961577]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - initialize: Supports id properties, got a vulkan device UUID
2024-11-18 12:49:57,059 [ 961689]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Critical:
2024-11-18 12:49:57,059 [ 961689]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Warning:
2024-11-18 12:49:57,059 [ 961689]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Warning:
2024-11-18 12:49:57,059 [ 961689]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Warning:
2024-11-18 12:49:57,059 [ 961689]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Warning:
2024-11-18 12:49:57,059 [ 961689]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Warning:
2024-11-18 12:49:57,059 [ 961689]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Warning:
2024-11-18 12:49:57,059 [ 961689]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Warning:
2024-11-18 12:49:57,059 [ 961689]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\Claudiu\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-35.2.10.db, detection is enabled for process: 12652
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Crash reports will be automatically uploaded to: https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - library_mode host gpu mode host
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - emuglConfig_get_vulkan_hardware_gpu: Using gpu 'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 730' for vulkan support
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - 
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - android_startOpenglesRenderer: gpu infoGPU #1
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Make: 8086
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Model: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 730
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Device ID: 4682
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:56.900836   20004 HealthMonitor.cpp:279] HealthMonitor disabled.
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:56.900924   20004 VulkanDispatch.cpp:137] Added library: vulkan-1.dll
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - W1118 12:49:56.926278   20004 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1169] Selecting Vulkan device: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 730, Version: 1.3.293
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:57.028554   20004 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1531] Initializing VkEmulation features:
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:57.028563   20004 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1532]     glInteropSupported: true
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:57.028565   20004 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1533]     useDeferredCommands: true
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:57.028566   20004 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1535]     createResourceWithRequirements: true
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:57.028568   20004 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1536]     useVulkanComposition: false
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:57.028569   20004 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1537]     useVulkanNativeSwapchain: false
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:57.028570   20004 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1538]     enable guestRenderDoc: false
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:57.028571   20004 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1539]     ASTC LDR emulation mode: 2
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:57.028572   20004 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1540]     enable ETC2 emulation: true
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:57.028573   20004 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1541]     enable Ycbcr emulation: false
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:57.028574   20004 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1542]     guestVulkanOnly: false
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:57.028575   20004 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1543]     useDedicatedAllocations: false
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:57.028763   20004 FrameBuffer.cpp:522] Graphics Adapter Vendor Google (Intel)
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:57.028769   20004 FrameBuffer.cpp:523] Graphics Adapter Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Intel(R) UHD Graphics 730)
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:57.028770   20004 FrameBuffer.cpp:524] Graphics API Version OpenGL ES 3.0 (4.5.0 - Build 32.0.101.6078)
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:57.028771   20004 FrameBuffer.cpp:525] Graphics API Extensions GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - I1118 12:49:57.028773   20004 FrameBuffer.cpp:526] Graphics Device Extensions N/A
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Sending adb public key [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 @unknown]
2024-11-18 12:49:57,060 [ 961690]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Ignoring invalid parameter detected in function: 0000000000000000 file: 0000000000000000, line: 0, expression: 0000000000000000
2024-11-18 12:49:57,075 [ 961705]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - C:\Users\Claudiu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: WHPX: Failed to setup partition, hr=c0350005
2024-11-18 12:49:57,075 [ 961705]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - WHPX on Windows 10.0.21996 detected.
2024-11-18 12:49:57,075 [ 961705]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - C:\Users\Claudiu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: failed to initialize WHPX: Invalid argument
2024-11-18 12:49:57,075 [ 961705]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - QEMU main loop exits abnormally with code 1
2024-11-18 12:49:57,097 [ 961727]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - netsimd I 11-18 10:49:57.980 daemon\src\rust_main.rs:98 - netsim artifacts path: "C:\\Users\\Claudiu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\netsimd"
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - netsimd I 11-18 10:49:57.981 daemon\src\rust_main.rs:101 - NetsimdArgs {
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - fd_startup_str: None,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - no_cli_ui: true,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - no_web_ui: true,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - pcap: false,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - disable_address_reuse: false,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - hci_port: None,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - connector_instance: None,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - instance: None,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - logtostderr: false,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - dev: false,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - rust_grpc: false,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - rust_hostapd: false,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - rust_slirp: false,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - vsock: None,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - config: None,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - host_dns: Some(
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - "8.8.8.8",
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - ),
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - http_proxy: None,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - wifi_tap: None,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - test_beacons: false,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - no_test_beacons: false,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - no_shutdown: false,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - verbose: false,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - version: false,
2024-11-18 12:49:57,098 [ 961728]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - }
2024-11-18 12:50:07,303 [ 971933]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Process finished with exit code 1
2024-11-18 12:50:07,303 [ 971933]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 9 API 35 - Emulator terminated with exit code 1
2024-11-18 12:50:22,825 [ 987455]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity to files
2024-11-18 12:50:22,826 [ 987456]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity to files
2024-11-18 12:50:24,924 [ 989554]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity to files
2024-11-18 12:50:24,924 [ 989554]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity to files

Nothing seems to work, and it drives me nuts...
